# Few On-Demand data tables are not showing data in spotfire report when refreshed manually

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have 18 On Demand data tables in my dashboard and I invoke them manually with a Submit button. When I checked in SQL logs all my Info Links are executed properly but my dashboard is not showing up the data for 2-3 tables.. Moreover, I see ***needs refresh*** icon beside my table visualization despite the Successful Info Links Execution.
When I click on Submit Button again for the second time then the dashboard will show me the data for those 2-3 left over tables. During the second step Submit, Info links will not execute as they are already executed..

How to resolve this issue? I am expecting all my data to be loaded when I click on Submit button for the first time itself. 
Any inputs would be much helpful to proceed further.

**Script to Refresh/fetch my On Demand Tables:**

```
if Table.IsRefreshable and Table.NeedsRefresh:
    Table.Refresh()
if Table1.IsRefreshable and Table1.NeedsRefresh:
    Table1.Refresh()
if Table2.IsRefreshable and Table2.NeedsRefresh:
    Table2.Refresh()
if Table3.IsRefreshable and Table3.NeedsRefresh:
    Table3.Refresh()
```

and so on.. where Table, Table1, Table2.. are my data table parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this would be fixed once the below hotfix is deployed to spotfire server.

**TS-55681 - Visualization does not always updates after refresh is done via Python script**

Thanks
San